# React - e.target.value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to return the string "blue" (so I can use setState to change the color) within:

```
<div className="colorBox blue" value="blue" onClick={changeColor}></div>
```

using this function:

```
const changeColor = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ color: e.target.value })
}
```

but I only receive undefined when I log it to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` element can't have **value** attribute, if you are trying to change color use `input` element of type **color**
`<input type="color" value="" />` .
**Example:**

```
<input type="color" value={//default color form your state} onChange={changeColor} 
const changeColor = (e) => {
    const color = e.target.value;
    this.setState({color});
}
```

for more information about input color checkout MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Answer (score 2):

The `div` tag **doesn't contain** the property `value` in the target object even if you add attribute.

If you want to get the value, you can use the `button` tag or input, but for your example, the button would be good.

**Here is the example:**

```
<button className="colorBox blue" value="blue" onClick={changeColor}></button>
```

**Same function:**

```
const changeColor = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ color: e.target.value })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. What other tags can I use other than the button tag?

Comment: @bgardne7 these all tags: `options, li, meter, progress, param, button and input`

Comment: we can also **role** and **type** attribute with button element